# How to decrypt xml in ionic 2?

Tags: xml, encryption, ionic-framework, ionic2, aes

I am looking to implement Decrypt functionality in my Ionic 2 app. I have an xml file that is encrypted by any third party tool by AES encryption.
Now I need to decrypt this file and render the content in my ionic 2 app.

I already implemented this in iOS by generated key (using password and salt key).but not able to do this in ionic 2.

I get to know how to parse xml in ionic 2.The only thing which are left is to start decrypt the xml file.If anyone know a little bit or any idea please let me know so that I can proceed with this.

Kindly anyone help me regarding the same by suggesting any library or framework.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API)? It seems to have quite good support now ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography)).